# ¿Cómo crear una ÚNICA lista a partir de líneas un archivo usando split y append?

Tags: python-3.x

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Quiero escribir un programa que me guarde todas las líneas de un archivo en una ÚNICA lista, específicamente utilizando los métodos split() y append().Ya busqué en diferentes fuentes y no encuentra una respuesta. He intentado entre varios códigos el de abajo, sin embargo, me crea una lista para cada línea. Lo que yo buscó es una sola lista que incluya todas las líneas y cuyos elementos sean las palabras por separado de todo el archivo.
Gracias!

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
palabras=list()
linesFile = fh.readlines()
for lines in linesFile:
    lines = lines.split()
    palabras.append(lines)
    print (lines
```

Comment: Es que debes imprimir es la lista palabras no la lista lines

Comment: Y debes imprimir palabras fuera del for.

Comment: Con esta línea `linesFile = fh.readlines()` ya tienes todo, ni se que esperas

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas! Esto es lo que espero:  ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder'], y obtengo una lista con varias sublistas dentro: [['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks'], ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun'], ['Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon'], ['Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']]

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un archivo tienes dos opciones:

- Leerlo línea a línea usando `readline`.
- Leerlo completo y obtener una lista de líneas usando `readlines`.

En ninguno de los dos casos necesitas hacer un `split`, ya que el archivo se entrega en líneas.

En este caso, lo más directo es leer el archivo completo de una sola vez:

```
with open("quijote.txt") as file:
    lista = file.readlines()
    print(lista[:10])
```

lee el Quijote completo en una lista y luego imprime sus diez primeras líneas.

```
['\n', 'El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha\n', '\n', 'TASA\n', '\n', 'Yo, Juan Gallo de Andrada, escribano de Cámara del Rey nuestro señor, de\n', 'los que residen en su Consejo, certifico y doy fe que, habiendo visto por\n', 'los señores dél un libro intitulado El ingenioso hidalgo de la Mancha,\n', 'compuesto por Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, tasaron cada pliego del dicho\n', 'libro a tres maravedís y medio; el cual tiene ochenta y tres pliegos, que\n']
```